# why state_hovered does not work for ListView items

Tags: android, listview

I have a singleChoice ListView with only one TextView item in xml file .
I tried to assign a selector to textView and change the background color of items when clicked.

The problem is that when i click on items , state-pressed and state_activated works but state_hovered (just for devices that has pen) does not work , while this selector works properly for other controls ?! what is the problem.

here is my selector file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/combo_hovered" android:state_hovered="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/combo_pressed" android:state_activated="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/combo_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/combo_unpressed"></item>

</selector>
```

Thank you for your help.